# C# + Pl/SQL Problem with out parameter in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
Get_Username
(
    p_Username IN user.USERNAME%TYPE,
    p_ReturningUsername OUT user.Username%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT username INTO p_ReturningUsername FROM user WHERE p_Username = username;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        p_ReturningUsername := null;
END;
```

I've executed it from the database and it worked perfectly.
When I execute it from c# app I don't get any value back.

```
public bool getUsername(string username)
    {
        OracleConnection connection = getConnection();
        OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("Get_Username", connection);
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("p_ReturningUsername", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("p_Username", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = username;

        try
        {
            oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Source: " + ex.Source);
        }


        string tmp = oracleCommand.Parameters["p_ReturningUsername"].Value.ToString();
        connection.Close();
        return tmp == username;
    }
```

For a WPF registration window I need to check if the username is already taken.
When I execute this code I receive an empty string when it has to be the username in the user table.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Codo says, add the line `command.BindByName = true;`, but also replace the line

```
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("p_ReturningUsername", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

with

```
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("p_ReturningUsername", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Replace the number `100` with the number of characters in your `username` column.

We use this overload of the `Add` method so that we can specify the size of the output parameter.  This allows the Oracle driver to make enough space to receive the value from the database.  The `null` argument is for the initial value of the parameter, which we don't care about because this is an output parameter, but we have to specify it as there is no overload of the `Add` method that takes only the name, type, size and direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, and now I understand how it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (I've just swapped two lines):

```
public bool getUsername(string username)
    {
        OracleConnection connection = getConnection();
        OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("Get_Username", connection);
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("p_Username", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = username;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("p_ReturningUsername", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Source: " + ex.Source);
        }


        string tmp = oracleCommand.Parameters["p_ReturningUsername"].Value.ToString();
        connection.Close();
        return tmp == username;
    }
```

Or add:

```
oracleCommand.BindByName = true;
```

By default, the `OracleCommand` class binds parameters by order, not by name.

Comment: That was my original code. I swapped it because I recive an exception executing this code:  Exception Message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "W1O67X.GET_USERNAME", line 9 ORA-06512: at line 1  Exception Source: Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
And I recive the same for the    BindByName